# TYPO3 Upgrade 6.2 to 7.6

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I upgraded my TYPO3 version 6.2.17 LTS to TYPO3 7.6.2 LTS.
But after the symlink changed, when I take the install tool, it displayed an error in a white screen like this;

Calculated absolute path to tslib directory does not exist.

> Something in the main file, folder and link structure is wrong and
> must be fixed!
>
> A typical document root contains a couple of symbolic links:
>
> - A symlink "typo3_src" pointing to the TYPO3 CMS core.
> - A symlink "typo3" - the backend entry point - pointing to "typo3_src/typo3"
> - A symlink "index.php" - the frontend entry point - points to "typo3_src/index.php"

My php version is 5.6.17. Please help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: I came into the same bug. Then I went back to TYPO3 6.2, cleared the caches in the Install Tool, deinstalled almost every other extension. Then the TYPO3 7.x installation could be started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes this may be due to php opcode cache. So by running below code, that clears the opcode cache, the issue can be solved by running this code

```
<?php
opcache_reset();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. I edited the answer to directly include the answer

Comment: I had a similar problem. Restarting php-fpm solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is most likely caused by an extension since the t3lib directory was already removed in 6.2 LTS. Try uninstalling custom extensions by setting their status in the `PackageStates.php` to `inactive`. Then remove the content of typo3temp and try again.